# Linking the file to download in a form without page url change

Tags: javascript, html, preventdefault

I'm writing a simple page with a form in JS. I also use ajax in this form. At the bottom of this form I have a checkbox with a link to pdf file with terms. I want to be able to download this file by clicking on a link.

```
<a href="#file_name" download="File.pdf" target="_top">
```

Downloading a file works, but the url changes - "#file_name" is added to my current url. How can I get rid of this "#" or prevent adding it?

Comment: I have run your code in chrome and the url is not changed. Could you post more code about this question?

Answer (score 0):

Try it. It should solve the problem

```html
    <a href="File.pdf" download >Download</a>
```